# How to understand how this map-reduce code works?

Tags: javascript

It's making the first row of a 2d array as the header.

In this part here, I don't understand what's happening:

```js
const fn = ([keys, ...values]) => 
  values.map(vs =>
    vs.reduce((acc, v, i) => (acc[keys[i]] = v, acc), {}))

const array = [
  [ 'combi', 'DQ#', 'sd', 'Level 3', 'Level 6', 'Level 7' ],
  [ 'DQn DQDC Simple','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple', 'Simple_A7',  0.262],
  [ 'DQn DQDC Simple1','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple1', 'Simple_A7',  0.264]
]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: (As an aside, the map-reduce function in this post appeared to be duplicated, so I removed the copy - feel free to edit further).

Comment: But it's all the code...

Comment: What it does is create an array of objects whose keys are the values from the 1st sub-array of `array` and whose values come from the 2nd and subsequent sub-arrays of `array`.

Comment: It's not clear from your post what your actual question is. Which part is not clear; the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)? The [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable)? The `reduce` function? The `map` function?

Comment: May be worth visualizing this code at [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html#mode=display) and stepping through it.

Comment: @Phil both and just the map and reduce, I don't understand what is that "VS" and [keys, ...values] and why is there a logical operator in the middle of nowhere "=>" those "acc" and "{}" with nothing inside...

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the PythonTutor, I'll definitely fav it here, very userful.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)? As for `(acc, v, i) => (acc[keys[i]] = v, acc)`, think of it as `function(acc, v, i) { acc[keys[i]] = v; return acc; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `fn` creates objects where the keys are from the first array in the 2d array and the values are from the other arrays.

The argument to fn is destructured: `const fn = ([keys, ...values])` after which `keys` is the first element of the array passed to `fn` and values is the rest (the remaining two arrays).

So we have:

```
array = [
    [ 'combi', 'DQ#', 'sd', 'Level 3', 'Level 6', 'Level 7' ],
    [ 'DQn DQDC Simple','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple', 'Simple_A7',  0.262],
    [ 'DQn DQDC Simple1','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple1', 'Simple_A7',  0.264]
]
```

then a call to fn: `const result = fn(array)`

after which, in `fn`, we have:

```
keys = ['combi', 'DQ#', 'sd', 'Level 3', 'Level 6', 'Level 7']
values = [
    ['DQn DQDC Simple', 'DQn', 'DQDC', 'Simple', 'Simple_A7', 0.262],
    ['DQn DQDC Simple1', 'DQn', 'DQDC', 'Simple1', 'Simple_A7', 0.264]
]
```

As the return value we have `map` being called on `values` which will give a new array of the same length as `values` where the values are the result of the function argument to `map` being applied to each of the values.

In this case the function sent to `map` is (formatted for clarity):

```
vs => vs.reduce(
    (acc, v, i) => (acc[keys[i]] = v, acc), 
    {}
)
```

which is an arrow function, and is (in this case) equivalent to:

```
function(vs) {
    return vs.reduce(
        function(acc, v, i){ return (acc[keys[i]] = v, acc) }, 
        {}
    )
}
```

(Arrow functions behave differently to other function types in some ways, but for this case it makes no difference. You can read up on arrow functions here: [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

So for the first element we have `vs = ['DQn DQDC Simple', 'DQn', 'DQDC', 'Simple', 'Simple_A7', 0.262]` and we apply `reduce` to it. `reduce` accumulates values based on the elements of the array and accumulates them in the accumulator `acc` which will have as it's initial value the second argument to `reduce`, namely `{}`, an empty object.

The function sent as the first argument to `reduce` was:

```
(acc, v, i) => (acc[keys[i]] = v, acc)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
function (acc, v, i) {
    acc[keys[i]] = v
    return acc
}
```

So for each element in this array we run that function. `acc` is the accumulator, `v` is the value of the array currently being processed, and `i` is the index of that element in the array.

The statement `acc[keys[i]] = v` will set a property on the object `acc` with the name `keys[i]` and value `v`. The return value will be the accumulator in the next round of processing. In this case the return value is `acc`, because of the comma operator being used. The comma operator takes two statements, evaluates both and returns the value of the second. So `acc[keys[i]] = v` will be evaluated and then `acc` will be returned and will then be the `acc` for the next element to be processed.

So for the first element, 0, we get `keys[0] = 'combi'`, `v[0] = 'DQn DQDC Simple'`, and `acc = {}` which gives:

```
acc = {
    combi: 'DQn DQDC Simple'
}
```

and the return value of `(acc[keys[i]] = v, acc)` will be `acc`, so `{ combi: 'DQn DQDC Simple' }`.

For the second element, 1, we get `keys[1] = 'DQ#'`, `v[1] = 'DQn'`, and `acc = { combi: 'DQn DQDC Simple' }` which gives:

```
acc = {
    combi: 'DQn DQDC Simple',
    DQ#: 'DQn'
}
```

and so on until we are done with the array which means we have the first element of our final result:

```
acc = {
    'combi': "DQn DQDC Simple",
    'DQ#': "DQn",
    'sd': "DQDC",
    'Level 3': "Simple",
    'Level 6': "Simple_A7",
    'Level 7': 0.262
}
```

Then the whole thing is done again for the next/last array in `values`:

```
['DQn DQDC Simple1', 'DQn', 'DQDC', 'Simple1', 'Simple_A7', 0.264]
```

giving:

```
acc = {
    'combi': "DQn DQDC Simple",
    'DQ#': "DQn",
    'sd': "DQDC",
    'Level 3': "Simple1",
    'Level 6': "Simple_A7",
    'Level 7': 0.264
}
```

And, finally, `map` will return an array with those two objects as elements in it's result array:

```
result = [
    {
        'combi': "DQn DQDC Simple",
        'DQ#': "DQn",
        'sd': "DQDC",
        'Level 3': "Simple",
        'Level 6': "Simple_A7",
        'Level 7': 0.262
    },
    {
        'combi': "DQn DQDC Simple",
        'DQ#': "DQn",
        'sd': "DQDC",
        'Level 3': "Simple1",
        'Level 6': "Simple_A7",
        'Level 7': 0.264
    }
]
```

Comment: A truly amazing explanation and write-up. The only suggestion I'd make is to not mutate the accumulator in the reduce callback. IMO, it also makes for cleaner code... `(acc, v, i) => ({ ...acc, [ keys[i] ]: v })`

Comment: Thanks @Phil! I appreciate the comment!
Good point! I agree that your example makes things cleaner and better. I wanted to stick to explaining the code rather than commenting too much on it. Otherwise I might also add that in general the comma operator risks making things more difficult to understand - particularly for anyone who hasn't come across it before.

Comment: Thanks @stoen, that is even better than what I was looking for. All the information is clean and detailed, really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome @KaioPatrick! I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Old school equivalent code:

```js
function fn(arr) {
  // Destructuring assigment
  let keys = arr[0];
  let values = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    values.push(arr[i]);
  }
  
  // Map
  let mapResult = [];
  for (let valuesIndex in values) {
    let vs = values[valuesIndex];
    // reduce
    let acc = {}
    for (let i in vs) {
      let v = vs[i];
      let accKey = keys[i];
      acc[accKey] = v;
    }
    mapResult[valuesIndex] = acc
  }
  return mapResult
}

const array = [
  [ 'combi', 'DQ#', 'sd', 'Level 3', 'Level 6', 'Level 7' ],
  [ 'DQn DQDC Simple','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple', 'Simple_A7',  0.262],
  [ 'DQn DQDC Simple1','DQn',  'DQDC', 'Simple1', 'Simple_A7',  0.264]
]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice to learn it as well, very interesting! Thank you.